# Keyboard shortcut for indenting bulleted list in Gmail message editor with Mac

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

How to indent a bulleted list in Gmail message editor with Mac, Chrome & Finnish keyboard?

Bulleted list can be toggled with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> -> Works OK.

Gmail editor's button has tooltip with shortcuts <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (indent) <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (de-indent). However, I haven't been able to succesfully do that since in Mac Chrome those shortcuts are mapped for for History -> Back & History -> Forward

Something I've tried:

- Plain `[` & `]` can be entered with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> & <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> on my keyboard
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> & <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>: History -> Back & History -> Forward
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> : Nothing
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> : Selects previous/next tab
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> : Changes to 7th tab
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (in Finnish keyboard <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>) : Opens "Help" menu at Mac menu bar.

Not so crucial but would speed up email writing every now and then.

Comment: BTW: I tried to tag this with "indentation" & "finnish-keyboard" but don't have enough reputation here. Please feel free to tag with those if you think those would be relevant :)

Comment: I have the same problem with my German Mac keyboard and Firefox. There, plain [ and ] are entered via Alt+5 and Alt+6, but in combination with ⌘, nothing happens.

Comment: Revisited this. Command+[ & Command+] seem to be History->Back & History->Forward in Chrome. Hmm...

Comment: hmm command+[/] is working for me

Comment: Thanks @chrismarx , tried also that, didn't work :( (I updated the list above)

Comment: (Added the History->Back & History->Forward to question description also)

Comment: Unfortunately, even the "Custom Keyboard Shortcuts" Lab doesn't have options to change the keys for indent.

Answer (score 8):

I am able to use the following shortcuts:

- Indent: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>
- Outdent: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: For me (with Finnish keyboard) that doesn't work. 

On Finnish keyboard `{` and `}` are got with Shift+Alt+8 and Shift+Alt+8, so probably modifiers mess that up or something

Comment: Does not work on a German keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Original poster suggested following key combination to type a bullet (·):

> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>

For some reason, that does not work for me (macOS Sierra & Finnish keyboard layout). I get a bullet by pressing following keys:

> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

I hope this helps if anybody else has same problem.

Comment: To clarify a bit, for me <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> does not type a bullet but starts/toggles a bullet list.

Answer (score 0):

To indent further inside, you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

To indent outside, i.e. to decrease indent, you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> with the bullet being empty.

Comment: In my gmail, if I press `Tab` while on a bullet point, the focus is moved out from the message text field to Send button.

`Enter` on an empty bullet works for decreasing indent

Answer (score -1):

Yes there are various shortcuts available for indenting the bullet list in gmail message editor with Mac.These shortcut keys are like :-
Ctrl+shift+7 is the shortcut key for numbered list.
Ctrl+shift+8 is the shortcut key for a bullet list.
The above both the shortcut keys are useful for the Google Docs also.